# Object detection using ToF sensor

Tags: mobile-robot, sensors, laser

I am making an indoor robot and in order to detect static and dynamic objects I have decided to go with ST VL53L1X ToF proximity sensor, here is the link:
https://www.st.com/en/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/vl53l1x.html

My question is, will this sensor show me a 3D reconstruction of what the sensor actually sees by emitting a light? And what is the difference between this sensor and other 3D ToF cameras?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you say "3D reconstruction?" Lidar units will generally just return a line (or set of lines) of points. You index those points via the pose of the sensor platform and can build your own point cloud of return data.

**The item you linked is not a lidar unit**. It is a laser range finder. I didn't see any specs on measurement accuracy, and there are no specs on horizontal or vertical resolution. The device you linked emits a single beam and returns information on how far that beam traveled before contacting a surface.

It's possible for you to have a mechanism (servos, etc.) that move this device around to create some custom scan, but even then it's a single point measuring at 50 Hz. You get 50 points per second. Most laser scanners generate tens to hundreds of thousands of points per second.

Again, the definition of "3D reconstruction" is up to you, but I don't think this sensor is what you're looking for.